# Percent of the Way to

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

I have a program which specifies commencement and completion activities, we'll call them "A" and "B" respectively. It then outputs the percent of duration between them that hasn't elapsed:

> Percentage of the way from A to B: 13%

The "of the way" feels very uncomfortable and unnecessary yet without the phrase I like it even less:

> Percentage from A to B: 13%

Is there a way that I can more clearly state that this is the fraction of the total time between A and B that remains?

Comment: You're being redundant with with the word 'percentage'.  Consider "Progress from A to B: 13%"

Answer (score 1):

Percentage of the *time between* A and B. Or for a more natural sentence structure "X percent of the time between event A and event B" where X is the percentage you want to talk about.